# Javascript Multiply Ttable

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to enter a number on an input and then enter a number with on a prompt. The first number on the input is the number where the table should be seen and should serve to prompt the count at how far the table by must count.

For example:
*Input* : **5** *Prompt* : **6**
1 x **5**   2 x **5** 3 x **5** 4 x **5** 5 x **5** 6 x **5**

I hope you can help me with this. Thank You

You can enter any random number and according to me the best you can do with a for-loop.

html:

```
<input type="submit" value="uitrekenen" onclick="Multiply(x,y);" />
```

javascript:

```
var x=Numb er (prompt("vul een getal in"));
var y=Number (prompt("Vul een getal in"));


function Multiply(x,y){
    document.write(x*y + "<br />"); 
}
```

Comment: Did you mean something like a for loop (e.g. `for( var i = 1; i <= y; i++){ document.write(i+" * "+x+"<br/>"); }`? Or do you want to eval the expression (e.g. `for( var i = 1; i <= y; i++){ document.write((i*x)+"<br/>"); }`?

Comment: thank you! but you have now two different codes. Can you make one code of it? so u see by the answer: 1x5=5 2x5=10 The multiply with a answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe like this? for( var i = 1; i <= y; i++){ document.write(i+" * "+x+" = "+(i*x)+"<br/>"); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for writing in HTML and Javascript is completely confused.

`<input type='submit'>` submits the form to which it belongs

`<input type='text'  name='myName' value='Initial Value'>` is for entering text, which can be converted to a number later. What is entered is its value.

Any prompts are written before or after these.

The use of document.write will completely overwrite your page.

Add in a `<div>` to contain your results.

document.getElementById() is a reference to a particular `<div>` with a given id

.innerHTML will put text into a `<div>`

HTML

```
<form name='form1' onsubmit=mult()>
    Vul een getal in <input type='text' value='' name='input' /><br>
    Vul een getal in <input type='text' value='' name='promp' /><br>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<div id='answer'></div>
```

Javascript

```
function mult() {
    var tableList='';
    var base=parseInt(document.forms['form1']['input'].value); //parseInt to convert string to integer
    var howMany=parseInt(document.forms['form1']['prompt'].value);
    for(var i=1; i<=howMany; i++) {
        tableList += i+'x'+base+' ';
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML=tableList;
```

Suggest you find basic tutorials in HTML and Javascript

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/nAX88/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Multiply(){
    var x = +document.getElementById('num1').value;
    var y = +(prompt("Vul een getal in"));
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById('resultDiv');
    resultDiv.value='';
    for (i=1;i<=y;i++){
       resultDiv.value += i + " x " + x + "\n";
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="num1" />
<input type="button" value="uitrekenen" onclick="Multiply()" />
<textarea id="resultDiv"></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you very much. It works! but i dont see the answer when i typ a multiply.